# Как запретить выполнение cron через браузер

Tags: php

как можно запретить выполнение cron если пользователь перейдет по ссылке https://ссылка сайта/cron.php ?

Нашел вот такой вариант

```
function isCommandLine() {
   return defined('STDIN');
}
```

Но тогда cron не выполняется через планировщик задач.
Использую виртуальный хостинг.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php
или
аргументом в CLI передать переменную, наличие которой будет означать что скрипт выполняется не из web

Comment: Самый правильный вариант — вообще убрать ссылку на cron.php, вынеся его за пределы папки public_html (то же самое относится и ко всем другим php-файлам, кроме тех, которым действительно нужны ссылки)